# Why does all the text disappear when I try to make a login component in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So first of all this is my code

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Login from "./components/Login";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path = "/">
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>

      <h2> Testar </h2>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**and this is for Login.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const Login = (props) => {
    return <div> Login </div>
};

export default Login;
```

I expected "Login" to be written out but it doesn't. In addition to that, my text where it says "test" also disappears. Do anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Try checking the browser dev tools console. It might have some errors logged there.

Comment: `path = "/"`  Wouldn't you want the path to be something like -> `/login` ?

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? Normally it's something like `<Route path="/" element={<Login />} />`

Comment: Use route like this <Route path="/" element={<Login />}>